# C++ function return reference

Tags: c++

Why is it that I cannot/shouldn't return the reference to a local variable to a function? Is it because the temporary variable is automatically destroyed after the function finishes executing?

```
const string & wrap(string & s1, const string & s2){
    string temp;
    temp = s2 + s1 + s2;
    return temp;
}
```

What about this one:

```
const string & wrap2(const string & s1, const string & s2){
    return (s2 + s1 + s2);  
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: yes, the variable is destroyed, and you will return a reference to a variable which doesn't excist anymore

Comment: There's another function I need clarifications on. See edit.

Comment: Your second function is just the short form of the first (probably the compiler optimizes into the second form), so it is still wrong. You need to return a std::string.

Comment: The second question depends on the implementation of operator+, but assuming a typical setup its the same. A reference to a temporary and a reference to a local variable are the same in this case. Both go poof.

Comment: @ultimatebuster if you're asking this because you're worried about unnecessary or excessive object copying, you can pass a third string argument(out parameter) by reference. You would then write the result to this string instead of returning a string. Usually you don't have to worry about this though because modern compilers are smart enough to optimize the extra copy away if it can(return value optimization).

Comment: I'm just learning C++. I'm transferring skills from Python, which is vastly different. I want to make sure I don't make some mistakes that's gonna be impossible to debug by understanding all the concepts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables declared locally inside functions are allocated on the stack. When a function returns to the caller, the space on the stack where the variable used to reside is reclaimed and no longer usable and the variables that were there no longer exist (well they do but you can't use them, and they can be overwritten at any time). So yeah, basically what you said.

Comment: What if the function belongs to a class and returns the reference of an object it contains ?

Comment: @locke14, If the object is declared outside the Method then it is not destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

That's exactly it.  The local variable goes *poof* and is destroyed when it goes out of scope.  If you return a reference or pointer to it, that reference or pointer will be pointing at garbage since the object won't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

> "What about this one:
>   ..."

`s2 + s1 + s2` is itself a temporary local variable, so it can't be returned by reference either.

What you could do - but please don't, this is a memory leak! - is

```
const string & wrap2(const string & s1, const string & s2){
  string *pt = new string(s2+s1+s2);
  return *pt;
}
```

This creates a globally valid string, which can then be passed by reference because it's not destroyed after the function finishes executing. In fact, it's *never ever* destroyed and will occupy space as long as the program runs: you probably don't want that!

If it wasn't a `const` reference you could, however, `delete` it manually.

**EDIT:** so it turns out that you can even delete the const reference, but again - that's not really nice to do.

Comment: You can still delete it manually. For example this compiles OK http://ideone.com/dcUg3 . However I'd say its still a bad thing to do. Returning a reference has the implicit meaning that something else is controlling the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't know that - seems a little weird that you can delete something while you're not allowed to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous posters said, it is because local variables end up on the stack. That physical memory could end up being given to another function frame and changed, all while you're pointer is still hanging on to the same location (which is now changed). I am not sure, but I don't think is is "destroyed", but it certainly isn't protected from being changed by any future stack allocations.

Comment: `string temp` is destroyed. Its destructor is called when the function returns.