# implementing a constant reference in c++ (following the weiss book)

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to follow the book Data structures and problem solving using c++, by weiss.

I'm trying to work on constant reference class just as the book says, but it keeps giving me compile errors.

Update: I changed the code, but some of the old errors persist.

```
//Class that wraps a constant reference variable.
//useful for return values from a container find method.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NullPointerException: public exception{

};

template <class Object>
class Cref{
   public:
    Cref() : obj(NULL){}
    explicit Cref( const Object & x): obj( &x){ }

    const Object & get() const{
        if(isNull()){
            throw NullPointerException( );
        }
        else{
            return *obj;
        }
    }
    bool isNull( ) const{
        return obj == NULL;
    }

private:
    const Object* obj; //stores a pointer...
```

};

//Usage example:

class TestClass{
    int test;

```
public:
    TestClass():test(10){}

    int& get(bool valid){
        if(valid){
            Cref<int> retv(test);
            return retv;
        }
        else{
            Cref<int> retv;
            return retv;

        }
    }
```

};

```
int main( ){
    TestClass temp;
    try{
        Cref<int> test = temp.get(true);
        Cref<int> test2 = temp.get(false);
    }
    catch(exception& e){
        cout<<"NULL pointer exception occurred"<<endl;
    }

}

3_ConstRef.cpp: In member function ‘int& TestClass::get(bool)’:
3_ConstRef.cpp:44:12: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘Cref<int>’
3_ConstRef.cpp:48:12: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘Cref<int>’
3_ConstRef.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
3_ConstRef.cpp:59:33: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Cref<int>’ requested
3_ConstRef.cpp:60:35: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Cref<int>’ request
```

ed

How do I solve these problems?
(p.s: Is it because of wrong implementation, or the wrong usage?)

Thank you : )

Comment: What's the `NullPointerException` definition? We don't know it. And you haven't included any header that could contain it.

Comment: ...I thought it was a c++ keyword when my gedit colored it....so do I need to define it myself??? or do I have to include more header files?

Comment: oh sorry, it wasn't (and the coloring didn't happen) I guess I need to implement it by myself

Comment: C++ doesn't have a `NullPointerException`, you may want to check if your book defines that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`3_ConstRef.cpp: In member function ‘const Object& Cref<Object>::get() const’:
3_ConstRef.cpp:15:33: error: there are no arguments to ‘NullPointerException’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘NullPointerException’ must be available [-fpermissive]`

`NullpointerException` is not dependent on your template arguments, so there should be a global declaration of the function. It seems you missed to include some headers. See this link for more details:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html

`3_ConstRef.cpp: In member function ‘int& TestClass::get(bool)’:
3_ConstRef.cpp:41:12: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘Cref<int>’
3_ConstRef.cpp:45:12: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘Cref<int>’`

In `TestClass::get()` you are trying to return an object of type `Cref<int>` but the return type is `int&`. It is not advisable to return return a reference of a local object, see this SO question:

[C++ function return reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985798/c-function-return-reference)

Comment: I just solved the error (by defining the NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION inside the code), but thanks anyway : )